# How do I run two "Find and Replace" at once in VS-Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, markdown, text-editor

I am working in `Markdown` and I realised I am looking for my `<code>` sections to be in bold.

If I run Find and Replace on the element:

```
<space>`<unique_code_snippet>`<space>
```

and replace all instances of:

```
<space>`
```

with:

```
<space>`**
```

This does not work because the code becomes:

```
<space`**<unique_code_snippet>`**<space>
```

That surrounds a `<code>` element to become:

```
**`<space>
```

Is there a way I can access both instances of

```
<space>`<and>`<space>
```

and replace with:

```
<space>'**<unique_code_snippet>**'<space>
```

In one Find and Replace action in VS-Code?

I could do this with TWO `Find and Replace` actions, but I'd rather not

Comment: I 'Flagged this comment' because, at the time of you writing this passive aggressive comment, I happened to be editing my question for clarity and politeness. Some of us work in different ways. Maybe read up on refactoring - https://www.goodreads.com/shelf/show/refactoring

Comment: do the backticks belong to the search

Comment: yes backticks belong to the search

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use regex search and replace

- find: `` <space>(`<unique_code_snippet>`)<space> ``
- replace: `<space>**$1**<space>`

If you want to replace ALL code sections with bold versions in one go

- find: `` <space>(`[^`]+`)<space> ``
- replace: `<space>**$1**<space>`

Comment: Thanks! So no options from within vs-code?

Comment: VSC can do regex find replace, press the `.*` button in the find dialog @Rartiste